# Deploying python script that uses uncommon modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, deployment, pyinstaller

Suppose I have a python script that uses many uncommon modules. I want to deploy this script to sites which are unlikely to have these uncommon modules. What are some convenient way to install and deploy this python script without having to run "pip" at all the sites?

I am using python v3.x

Comment: pyinstaller or cx_freeze

Comment: You can use Docker

Comment: WIth uncommon modules I assume modules that are not listed on PyPI, correct? You can copy those modules into your project folder so they are automatically installed when installing your project. You can bundle them into e.g. a debian package and reference its path with `PYTHONPATH`. The advantage here is you can also add non-python files like systemd service files. The possibilities are endless. You need to be more specifc what your use cases are since there is no ideal solution.

Comment: Please define "uncommon modules"

Comment: Need a lot more context to understand the best solution, but this seems like a good use case for docker containers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pyinstaller with spec file would be an option. uncommon modules should be specified in hidden import parameters

```
pyinstaller [options] script [script …] | specfile
```

deployment arguments can be stored in spec file and pyinstaller can be executed with the entry python file as following command

```
pyinstaller start.py myscript.spec
```

[sample spec file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html)

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
     pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
     binaries=None,
     datas=None,
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=None,
     runtime_hooks=None,
     excludes=None,
     cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
     cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,... )
coll = COLLECT(...)
```

see [pyinstaller help](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can create a python package with all the uncommon modules in your project and upload to a feed, could be public feed like www.pypi.org where all the pip installs are downloaded from or it could be your organizations azure devops artifacts.

After uploading your package, you only need to pip install  from the feed that you have chosen.